# Does a small Bonus for an unpaid internship need to be reported or taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, payroll-taxes, f1-student-visa

I did an unpaid internship in fall 2019, at the end I was given an amount below $500 as a small bonus for my work their. It came from a personal account of my boss, so my question if that money needs to be reported or taxed? Plus I am an international student and i didn't have any other income for the entire year of 2019 except for that amount.